# Copy a table to another table with different structure

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, data-structures

I have 2 tables in the DB:

```
Table1
Table1_Temp
```

The Table1_Temp was generated from a CSV. it is almost identical to Table1 but different because all Table1_Temp fields are VARCHAR and it has some irrelevant fields.

I need to move the Data from Table1_Temp to Table1 but to keep the structure of Table1, and disregard the unnecessary fields from Table1_Temp.

How can I do it?

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQL-Server? What are the structures of the two tables? What do you need to convert from varchar to? How do you define an "unnecessary field"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose the columns to use and cast them to the necessary type in your select

```
insert into table1 (col1, col2, col3)
select cast(col1 as signed), col5, col7
from Table1_Temp
```

Comment: What Can I do if I have NULL values in fields that should be converted to INT?
How can I clean them before?

Comment: What do you mean? YOu have contraint errors? You need to be way more specific in your question.

Answer (score 1):

if both tables are on a different database (and different column)

```
INSERT INTO db1.table1 (Acol1, Acol2, Acol3)

SELECT Bcol1 AS Acol1, Bcol2 AS Acol2, Bcol3 AS Acol3

FROM db2.table1_temp
```

This will only work if both databases are under 1 server (in this instance "localhost")