# Copy a database table to another database table with a different structure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am aware this was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19289879/copy-a-table-to-another-table-with-different-structure). However it doesn't answer my question. I have 10 tables in a database called "merged". I am taking a bunch of other databases with an identical structure as "merged" except that "merged" has an extra column that is a combination of two columns in the table. I am trying to transfer all this data into merged but I believe the extra column I believe is preventing the transfer.

```
    SqlCommand MergeDB = connDestination.CreateCommand();

        string sqlMergeDB = "";        

        int a= 0;
        for (a=0; a < tablenames.Length; a++){
      string sqlMergeDB = "INSERT INTO sql_merged.dbo." + tablenames[a] + " SELECT * FROM sourceForMerged.dbo." + tablenames[a];    
using (SqlDataReader reader = MergeDB.ExecuteReader()) {
        while(reader.Read()) 
        {
        MessageBox.Show("Transfered a table");
        }
        }
    }
```

The error occurs at the SqlDataReader row of the code above, which I believe means there is something wrong with the sql command. Please help. Thanks

Comment: You are missing a space after table name. Change the second string " SELECT..."

Comment: You are correct, but that is just on the post. The code has one

Comment: You also say "The error occurs at the SqlDataReader row of the code above", what error message do you get?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you name all the columns in both parts of the INSERT . . . SELECT statement you can map which source column gets inserted into which destination column.

If you imagine `TargetTable (Name, ProductType, Date)` and `SourceTable (Date, Type, Name)` then using:

```
INSERT INTO TargetTable (Name, ProductType, Date)
  SELECT Name, Type, Date FROM SourceTable
```

would move the three columns into the appropriate columns even though the order doesn't match.

If you have "extra" columns in one table or the other you can either leave them out or provide expressions to fill them in:

```
INSERT INTO TargetTable (Name, ProductType, Date, CombinedValues)
  SELECT Name, Type, Date, (ValCol1 + ' '  + ValCol2) FROM SourceTable
```

has four columns receiving data from four expressions, one of which concatenates two columns worth of data.  (In real life, you may find that the concatenation expression is more complicated, but this is the basic idea).

Comment: Each table has different columns and there are too many columns to write out. Which is also something I should have mentioned in the question. My bad. How do I account for this?

Comment: It is also technically a one column shift, so could I just say; add table[col] = tableDestination[col + 1]?

Comment: No, they do not have "too many columns to write out".  You just don't want to write them out.  Bite the bullet and do it the right way.  Otherwise your code will be very fragile: if one table has columns in a different order you may not find it until you've been running your database with bad data for weeks.

Comment: @BenC. Well, if it is "too many columns to write out", then write a loop which will generate the statement! And BTW, you can also write a plain SQL statement which generates your SQL statements.

Comment: Dude theres like 6 columns! You want me to write them all out?

Comment: Six is "too many to write out?" I've manually written similar queries for tables with at least two dozen columns.

Comment: I think Ben was making a little joke. . .

Comment: Possibly, I wasn't sure. But he was the OP and already made the statement that there were too many to write out, so I assumed. :|

Comment: @LarryLustig +1, but I'd also add that the values would be copied, not moved :)

Comment: @BenC. A real programmer never does "repeated tasks" ;) If you need to add more than 6 columns, then you should definively look for writing a construction loop.

Comment: A construction loop solves the (non) problem of writing out the columns but it does not allow you deal with (for instance) order issues which are not knowable from the db structure.  While I certainly believe in not repeating oneself, I believe this is a case in which "be clear" is more important.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a:

```
Insert Into [Table] Select * From [Table2]
```

unless the tables schemas are identical.  You would have to list out the columns for the Insert Statement.

If possible you could drop the column on the destination table and then add it back after the insert.

You could do something like this to build up you insert code if the table is very wide:

```
SELECT 
 'cmd.Parameter.Add("@' + column_name + '", SqlDbType.' + data_type + ');', 
  column_name 'Column Name',
  data_type 'Data Type'
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'TableName'
```

Comment: It is also technically a one column shift, so could I just say; add table[col] = tableDestination[col + 1]?

Comment: @BenC. If you are moving data from one column to another you will definitely have to Define your Columns in the insert.  You build you C# code using to sql to create the parameter blocks.

Comment: Nitpick: The schemas don't technically have to be identical.  `Table` can have more columns than `Table2` if the extra columns are nullable or have a default value, and the data types don't have to exactly match so long as the values in every row of `Table2` are implicitly convertible to the data type of the corresponding column in `Table`.

Comment: @cdhowie good point although it never seems to work that way for me :( lol